# Continues to loop even when user enters correct character

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I have been stuck at this for sometime and was wondering if anyone would be able to guide me. 
I am trying to let the user enter in a character and if it does not match one of the switch cases, then it should continue to ask the user. My code does that part fine. The issue comes up when the user tries to enter a correct character after and my code continues to output the default instead of the specific case.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you

```
 while(!flag){
            switch (endChar) {
                case 'T':
                case 't':
                    modFlags[0] = true;
                    flag = true;
                    break;
            case 'P':
            case 'p':
                modFlags[1] = true;
                flag = true;
                break;

            case 'W':
            case 'w':
                modFlags[2] = true;
                flag = true;
                break;

            case 'L':
            case 'l':
                modFlags[3] = true;
                flag = true;
                break;

            case 'I':
                System.out.print("sd");
                fileName = updateFileName(sc, fileName);
                flag = true;
                break;
            case 'i':
                fileName = updateFileName(sc, fileName);
                flag = true;
                break;

            case 'O':
            case 'o':
                break;

            case 'D':
            case 'd':
                break;

            case 'M':
            case 'm':
                modeBoth = true;
                flag = true;
                break;

            case 'H':
            case 'h':
                showMenu = false;
                flag = true;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Unknown Option.");
                System.out.print("Enter action: ");
                sc.next();
                break;
               // flag = false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where do you update `endChar`? You need to update it every time you go through the loop. You're missing that right now.

Comment: a single character is returned from another method (promptMenu) and assigned to endChar. I know that it is not updating endChar so that is why it keeps printing the same character over again but I am not sure how to update endChar without having the promptMenu method print everything else in it as well

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you provided, I suggest moving the scanning a value portion to the very beginning of your while loop and in the default case of your switch statement using just a `continue;` to bring you back to the beginning of the while loop. That way it will read in another value from input without having to code it again.

```
while(!flag){
        System.out.print("Enter action: ");
        endChar = sc.next().charAt(0);
        switch (endChar) {
        case 'T':
        case 't':
            modFlags[0] = true;
            flag = true;
            break;
        case 'P':
        case 'p':
            modFlags[1] = true;
            flag = true;
            break;

        case 'W':
        case 'w':
            modFlags[2] = true;
            flag = true;
            break;

        case 'L':
        case 'l':
            modFlags[3] = true;
            flag = true;
            break;

        case 'I':
            System.out.print("sd");
            fileName = updateFileName(sc, fileName);
            flag = true;
            break;
        case 'i':
            fileName = updateFileName(sc, fileName);
            flag = true;
            break;

        case 'O':
        case 'o':
            break;

        case 'D':
        case 'd':
            break;

        case 'M':
        case 'm':
            modeBoth = true;
            flag = true;
            break;

        case 'H':
        case 'h':
            showMenu = false;
            flag = true;
            break;

        default:
            continue;
    }

}
```

Comment: I was just in the middle of commenting to tell you what was wrong with this, when you edited it to fix it.  Good answer, and worthy of my upvote.

Comment: Yeah, realized it as I was pasting code, thanks. OP would be able to remove wherever he originally called for input from the scanner as a sidenote as well.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 sc.next();
```

near the bottom of the switch to

```
 endChar = sc.next().charAt(0);
```

because all you're currently doing is retrieving a `String` from the `Scanner` and not doing anything with it.  You need to assign a character of that `String` to `endChar` if you want the value of `endChar` to be different for the next iteration of the loop.